# User authentication using jQuery, Ajax, MySQL and Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, rest

I am developing a web application and created a Login page using HTML. The back-end is MySQL. Already established connection with the database using connection string and able to fetch data from MySQL(Through java program). I have to compare the entered username and password values with those in users table(MySQL). How can i get these entered values inside the java classes(where the database connection is established)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var userValue = document.getElementById('nameuser').value;
        var passValue = document.getElementById('passid').value;
        $.ajax({
            //code 
        });
    });
});
```

how can I achieve user authentication in such a scenario? Hoping this can be achieved with jQuery and Ajax. Needless to say, I am an amateur in Java and related technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data via ajax and run the sql `select * from tbl_user where username=$_POST['userValue'] and password=$_POST['passValue']` you need not compare the values if the result obtained for those combinations user exists else no user available display wrong username password alert.

```
             $.ajax({
                url: "url to link your database",
                type: "POST",
                data:{'userValue':userValue,'passValue':passValue},
                success: function(result) {
                }
             })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            url: "localhost:8080/yourProjectName/checkPasswordServlet",
            type: "POST",
            data:{'userValue':userValue,'passValue':passValue},
            success: function(result) {
                 console.log(result)
            }
         })
```

at the end side,if you use tomcat for http server, you can try servlet to receive data:
1.config the web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>checkPasswordServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.demo.login.checkPasswordServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>checkPasswordServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/checkPasswordServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2.in servlet like this:

```
 String userValue= request.getParameter("userValue");
 String passValue= request.getParameter("passValue");
```

3.compare with your data which from database,and return compare result to front side.